# Difficulty with returning and applying a value from a MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a function that will extract the userName of the user after I query my MongoDB via a unique ID (a GUID). I will have to do this at multiple points in my codebase so I've extracted the logic into its own helper function. Here is the function:

```
module.exports.getUserName = async function (GUID, callback) {
  try {
    var result = await User.findOne({
      GUID: GUID
    })

    callback(result['_doc'].fullname)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

If I `console.log(result['_doc'].fullname)` it returns what I want it to (the user's userName). However, when I try to activate this function in my route, the userName in the JSON object is returned as null. This is the function that is calling it:

```
dataset.comments.forEach(function(comment) {
    comment.timestamp = util.timestampToDate(comment.timestamp).getTime()

    Helper.getUserName(comment.userId, function(result) {
        comment.userName = result;
    })
});
```

If I `console.log(result)` inside that function and use Postman to hit up my route, it returns the correct name. If `console.log(comment)`, it returns the comment with the username attached.

However, when I run my route in Postman and locate a comment object, userName is listed as `null`. It's as if that function is never getting called.

When I call the route (I have restarted the server each and every time for sanity checking!) then the comments are returned as:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1521822257000,
    "actionId": "b9139c26-212b-4ebe-95a1-47c86f6c64ea",
    "text": "paul",
    "userId": "76889991-27f5-4613-b03a-17136e21a1aa",
    "userName": null,
    "userImage": "http://localhost:3001/api/users/76889991-27f5-4613-b03a-17136e21a1aa?image"
 },
```

`userName: null` is the problem here. How can I make that appear with the user's username instead of `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async functions` and `Promises` are a replacement for callbacks! So just do:

```
 async function getUserName (GUID, callback) {
   var result = await User.findOne({
     GUID: GUID
   });

   return result['_doc'].fullname;
 }
```

Then you can use `map` to map the array to an array of Promises, and then use `Promise.all` to wait for all queries to finish:

```
 await Promise.all(dataset.comments.map(async function(comment) {
   comment.timestamp = util.timestampToDate(comment.timestamp).getTime()

   comment.username = await Helper.getUserName(comment.userId);
 }));

 console.log(dataset.comments);
```

So now the data is logged *after* all comments were updated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jonas, but unfortunately it is still returning `null` when I check the API

Comment: Hey, I got a version of yours to work, so thank you for your help :)

Comment: @james glad to help :)